# JavaScript - Fixing that da*n caret symbol for calculator

Tags: javascript, math, symbols

I'm making a calculator in javascript and as of now it calculates:
`sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `cot`, `sec`, `csc` and also `arc` and `hyberbolic` of all subtypes,
`sqrt`, `cbrt`, `y-th root`, and `pow`. The problem is that I dont want to have the `pow(x,y)` as a function, I want to be able to type in for example:

```
2^3+2^4 # instead of pow(2,3)+pow(2,4)
```

How do I go about to get the function typed in as shown above? Here's the calculator for viewing it: http://calcy.comze.com/

Comment: There is no question in your post... Yes you can parse expression and compute it, but it is very unclear what you have problem with...

Comment: Have you looked at the tag description for "carrot"?

Comment: Ahhh!  I liked it with the carrot!

Comment: or just read the tiny little end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the formula in a string. Here is how you can do it:

Extend the numbr proto to have a `pow` method:

```
Number.prototype.pow = function(n){
   return Math.pow(this,n);
}
```

wrap every number around `()` and replace `^` with `.pow()`

```
str = str.replace(/[\d|\d.\d]+/g, function(n){
   return '(' + n + ')'
})
.replace(/\^/g, '.pow')
```

Eval the string

```
eval(str)
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/igegok/1/edit

Comment: well, are you sure that this will work and wont take the "3+2" in brackets so it will eval: pow(2,2+3)

Comment: Never ask before trying. Go in JSBin and replace the string with `"3+3"`. It would translate to `(3)+(2)` that will return same result.

Comment: ?, and what does the "Number.protocol" mean, explain it please i don't know what the protocol function does

Comment: Found a problem :(... can't eval that: "sqrt(2)^sqrt(2)"

Comment: do you have `sqrt` defined?

Comment: function sqrt(x,y) {if (y == undefined) {y = 2}; return Math.pow(x,1/y)}

Comment: how can i make it auto eval the functions before evaling pow?

Comment: ,only when using: "sqrt(2)^(sqrt(2))"

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your `^` notation to `pow` function, or `Math.pow` with regexp:

```
'2.14^3+ 2^2.5 - 12'.replace(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g, function(a, b, c) {
    return 'pow(' + b + ', ' + c + ')';
})
// pow(2.14, 3)+ pow(2, 2.5) - 12
```

With this approach you can even precalculate the power result and replace carots like this:

```
'2^3+ 2^2.5 - 12'.replace(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g, function(a, b, c) {
    return Math.pow(b, c);
});
// 8+ 5.656854249492381 - 12
```