# Wrap string in brackets but also having random value in string:

Tags: javascript, string

How can I wrap a string in parantheses that has another random value in it? Look at this for explaining better to understand:

```
var str = "ss(X)+ss(X)"
```

INTO:

```
"(ss(X))+(ss(X))"
```

NOTE: X can be any value like: "223" or "abc" "2+2+2"

Comment: What are the rules for placing parentheses? Are the substrings always separated by a `+` sign?

Comment: no, replaceing using regex

Comment: Freezy: start by forgetting about how to solve this (regexes or not) and start by better defining the problem first: what are the rules about what parts of the string are to be parenthesised? Once this is well defined (both when and when not to insert parentheses) the solution will follow.

Comment: The rules's to find any word with a paranthese infront of it with a depending value after that and then one more parantheses and wrap it into parantheses eg: "hello(2+2/32^2.2-sqrt(2)) + (lol(2))" into: "(hello(2+2/32^2.2-(sqrt(2)))) + (lol(2))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
str = str.replace(/\w*\(\d*\)/g, function () {return '(' + arguments[0] + ')';});
```

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69gBp/)

---

**EDIT**

Since you've changed the conditions, the task can't be done by Regular Expressions. I've put an example, how you can do this, at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAZby/). As a side effect, this snippet also detects possible odd brackets.

```
function addBrackets (string) {
    var str = '(' + string,
        n, temp = ['('], ops = 0, cls;
    str = str.replace(/ /g, '');
    arr = str.split('');
    for (n = 1; n < arr.length; n++) {
        temp.push(arr[n]);
        if (arr[n] === '(') {
            ops = 1;
            while (ops) {
                n++;
                temp.push(arr[n]);
                if (!arr[n]) {
                    alert('Odd opening bracket found.');
                    return null;
                }
                if (arr[n] === '(') {
                    ops += 1;
                }
                if (arr[n] === ')') {
                    ops -= 1;
                }
            }
            temp.push(')');
            n += 1;
            temp.push(arr[n]);
            temp.push('(');
        }
    }
    temp.length = temp.length - 2;
    str = temp.join('');
    ops = str.split('(');
    cls = str.split(')');
    if (ops.length === cls.length) {
        return str;
    } else {
        alert('Odd closing bracket found.');
        return null;
    }   
}
```

---

Just as a sidenote: If there's a random string within parentheses, like `ss(a+b)` or `cc(c*3-2)`, it can't be matched by any regular pattern. If you try to use `.*` special characters to detect some text (with unknown length) within brackets, it fails, since this matches also `)`, and all the rest of the string too...

Comment: But it doesn't suppor +,-,*,/

Comment: @FreezyIze You've edited your question (15 hours after I've answered it). In the original question you said, that there will be only digits within the parenthesis ("`NOTE: X can be any value like: "223" or "56".`" A direct citate from your _original_ question.) :-(. In a comment to Mike you said "`It is numbers but also large numbers like 12 with 2 digits"`. Anyway, `Regular Expressions` are supposed to parse _regular_ patterns, not _random_. I'm afraid you'll need a different approach to this task.

Comment: @FreezyIze I've edited my answer. Please check, if you can use it now.

Comment: Very good!!!, I can use it it's perfect!!, but only one problem, it doesn't support this: ss(ss(2)^ss(2)) INTO (ss((ss(2))^(ss(2))))

Comment: @FreezyIze Indeed it doesn't, it answers only to your question, not new demands. It's purposed to extract outer "functions" from the operators, but you can easily develope the code further, to check inner "functions" as well. Actually, if you're creating a calculator, it wouldn't be even necessary, since the code does this: `(ss(ss(2)^ss(2)))` which should be evaluateable as is.

Comment: See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/15037805/2101744

Comment: And this is my calculator: http://calcy.comze.com/

Comment: Umh... Too much TI-89 : ). I'd suggest you to fix these kind of things when ever user clicks the button or hits the key. Just catch those events, and modify the input before it's added to you evaluate string.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is random data, then this would be impossible, since you don't know what you actually want wrapped. Step 1: find out the condition for "this should be wrapped" versus "this should not be wrapped". We can then do a simple replacement:

```
var shouldbewrapped = /([a-zA-Z\(\)])+/g;
var wrapped = string.replace(shouldbewrapped, function(found) {
  return "(" + found + ")";
});
```

This does a regexp replace, but instead of replacing a string with a string, it replaces a string with the output of a function run on that string.

(note that the 'g' is crucial, because it makes the replace apply to all matches in your string, instead of stopping after running one replacement)

Comment: Looks good, but how the random number within parentehesis is taken account in your regexp?

Comment: Step 1: find out the condition for "this should be wrapped" versus "this should not be wrapped". If you have numbers, add that to the shouldbewrapped indicator.

Comment: No, it's random data in a specific part of the str.

Comment: if it's numbers, it's not random, it's quite rigidly \d+, and can be captured just like any other string sequence.

Comment: It is numbers but also large numbers like 12 with 2 digits

Comment: That doesn't matter, \d is a single digit, \d+ is "one or more digits". Also need decimal points? then we add that: /[\w\d\.\\(\\)]+/g, now we match everything string that consists of an unbroken sequence consisting only of letter, digits, (, ) or .

Answer (score 0):

I think your going to need to do some [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088382/why-use-string-interpolation). Then you can set up some `Math.random` or whatever you want to generate randomness with.