# JavaScript - Regex, is there a marker for any string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

str.replace(/\w*(\  || --> A marker whitch can represent any char or string? <-- ||  )/g, function() {return "(" + arguments[0] + ")"})

Comment: This question is related to OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15042565/1169519).

Answer (score 5):

The dot (`.`) matches any (1) character; `.+` matches a string of at least length 1, `.*` matches a string of at least length 0.

Answer (score 4):

A period is used to represent any character that is not a line break, but to represent any character you can use a set with two complementing sets, like all alphanumeric characters and all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
str = str.replace(/\w*([\W\w])/g, "($1)");
```

That will match a single character, if you want to match more than one you have to specify how many. `[\W\w]{1,3}` would for example match one to three characters. `[\W\w]+` would match everything to the end of the string.

Note that you don't need a callback for a simple replacement like this, just a string where `$1` is substituted with the first caught value.

---

Edit:
Come to think of it, as the character is following a set that matches alphanumeric characters, it has to be non-alphanumeric, so just `\W` will do:

```
    str = str.replace(/\w*(\W)/g, "($1)");
```

Comment: @FreezyIze: When I try it, I get exactly the expected output. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EaJSq/1/

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't search for "any string".

Comment: Please try out the answer above

Comment: @FreezyIze: That does the same, except it doesn't work for *all* characters. I already covered that in the first sentence of my answer.